# Is there anyway to check duplicate the message control id (MSH:10) in MSH segment using Mirth connect?

Tags: mirth

Is there anyway to check duplicate the message control id (MSH:10) in MSH segment using Mirth connect?

MSH|^~&|sss|xxx|INSTANCE2|KKLIU 0063/2021|20190905162034||ADT^A28^ADT_A05|Zx20190905162034|P|2.4|||NE|NE|||||

whenever message enters it needs to be validated whether duplicate of control id Zx20190905162034 is already processed or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database check (you can implement this using code template) is the easier way out. You might want to designate the column storing MSH:10 values as a primary key or define an index on it. Queries against unique entries would be faster. Other alternatives include periodically redeploying the Channel while reading all MSH:10 values already in the database and placing them in a global map variable or maintained in an API that you can make a GET request to when processing every message. Any of the options depends on the number of records we are speaking about.

Answer (score 2):

Mirth will not do this for you, but you can write your own JavaScript transformer to check a database or your own set of previously encountered control ids.

Your JavaScript can make use of any appropriate Java classes.

Comment: Thanks mjtrac, But it wont be a performance hit if we hit it every time to database whenever channel received message ?

Comment: Sure it will.  But that's what Mirth would have to do if it checked for you.  Isn't it inevitable if you need to check against all control ids previously encountered?